# How can I rewrite the following SQL query into LINQ query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to rewrite the following SQL query in LINQ. But my problem is that I don't know how to write an AND (&&) operator with a LINQ LEFT JOIN (look at my second left join).

```
SELECT      emp.EmployeeId,
            dsg.Name,
            pob.CompanyContribution,
            pob.EmployeeContribution,
            pob.OpeningIncome

FROM        HrmEmployees AS emp
LEFT JOIN   HrmDesignations AS dsg ON emp.HrmDesignationId=dsg.Id
LEFT JOIN   PfmOpeningBalance AS pob ON emp.Id=pob.HrmEmployeeId AND pob.CmnCalendarYearId=2
WHERE       emp.Id=6
```

I tried the following one. But getting compile error-

```
from emp in dbContext.EmployeeList
                        join dsg in dbContext.hrmDesig on emp.HrmDesignationId equals dsg.Id into DSGLeftJoin
                        from dsglj in DSGLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join pob in dbContext.PfOpeningBalances on emp.Id equals pob.HrmEmployeeId into POBLeftJoin
                        from poblj in POBLeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() && poblj.CmnCalendarYearId == clndrId
                        where emp.Id==empId
                        select new
                        {
                            empIdr = emp.Id,
                            EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId,
                            EmployeeName = emp.Name,
                            Designation = dsglj.Name,
                            OpeningIncome = poblj.OpeningIncome,
                            EmployeeContribution = poblj.EmployeeContribution,
                            CompanyContribution = poblj.CompanyContribution
                        }
```

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Comment: Yes, But getting compile error. May be the error is for wron syntax @Irshad

Comment: Show the code in the post so we can help

Comment: Otherwise we have no idea what you are using to put up this linq. Entity framework or entity classes etc.

Comment: Error messages frequently contain useful information. Rather than just telling us you "get an error", please include the actual error message.

Comment: This post is still missing a [mcve], and appears to have been abandoned, so it can be closed for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 (from emp in HrmEmployees
  join dsg in HrmDesignations 
  on  emp.HrmDesignationId equals dsg.Id
  join pob in PfmOpeningBalance 
  on emp.Id equals pob.HrmEmployeeId AND pob.CmnCalendarYearId equals 2
  into eGroup
  from emps in eGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
  emp.Id=6
  select new
    {
        EmployeeId =emp.EmployeeId,
        Name=dsg.Name,
        CompanyContribution=pob.CompanyContribution,
        EmployeeContribution=pob.EmployeeContribution,
        OpeningIncome=pob.OpeningIncome
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK you can try like this;

```
from emp in dbContext.EmployeeList
join dsg in dbContext.hrmDesig on emp.HrmDesignationId=dsg.Id
join pob in dbContext.PfOpeningBalanceson new {emp.Id, jp=pob.CmnCalendarYearId} equals new {pob.HrmEmployeeId, jp=2}
where emp.Id=6
select new {emp.EmployeeId,
            dsg.Name,
            pob.CompanyContribution,
            pob.EmployeeContribution,
            pob.OpeningIncome};
```

Or like this;

```
from emp in dbContext.EmployeeList.Where(e=>e.Id.Equals(6))
join dsg in dbContext.hrmDesig on emp.HrmDesignationId=dsg.Id
join pob in dbContext.PfOpeningBalanceson.Where(x=>x.CmnCalendarYearId.Equals(2)) on emp.Id equals pob.HrmEmployeeId
select new {emp.EmployeeId,
            dsg.Name,
            pob.CompanyContribution,
            pob.EmployeeContribution,
            pob.OpeningIncome};
```